# my custom adapter keeps going into the if statement instead of the else causing casting error even though the statement should evalute to false

Tags: java, android

I have a custom array adapter which should show 2 types of layouts in a list view. I differentiate between them with a Boolean called isMessage inside of the custom arrayAdapter. even though  isMessage is equal to true before passing the object MessageListDetails because I call prepareForIncomingMessage before adding the object.

```
   public class TimedEventsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    private List<Object> items;
    private boolean isMessage;
   //  * @param context
   //  * @param textViewResourceId
   //  * @param objects 
    public TimedEventsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Object> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId,objects);
        items = objects;
        isMessage = false;
    }
    public void prepareForIncomingMessage() {
        isMessage = true;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if(isMessage == false)
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.complete_event_discription, null);
           else
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.message_list_view, null);
        }
       if(isMessage == false){ // problem is here. even when I call prepareforincoming message it does not change the value of isMessage into true
        SoundDetails device = (SoundDetails) items.get(position);
        if (device != null) {
            TextView top = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
            TextView bottom = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
            Switch state = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.state);
            if (top != null) {
                top.setText(device.name);
            }
            if (bottom != null) {
                Date n = new Date();
                n.setTime(Long.parseLong(device.time));
                bottom.setText(n.getHours() +":"+n.getMinutes());
            }
            if (state != null)
                state.setChecked(device.IsEventActive);
                state.setTag(position);
        }
    } else{
            MessageListDetails MLD =  (MessageListDetails) items.get(position);
            TextView mainText;
            TextView subText;
            TextView messageTime;
            if(MLD != null){
             mainText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
             subText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactNumber);
             messageTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeToSend);
             mainText.setText(MLD.contactName);
             subText.setText(MLD.contactNumber);
             Date n = new Date();
             n.setTime(Long.parseLong(MLD.sendingTime));
             messageTime.setText(n.getHours() +":"+n.getMinutes());
             isMessage = false;
            }
        } 
        return v;
    } 
}
```

the exception clearly happens because it trys to cast the incoming object to Class SoundDetail while the incoming object is MessageDetailsList. here is the data log

```
       07-18 00:09:58.945: D/soundDetail(17589): inside of first statement
07-18 00:09:58.945: D/AndroidRuntime(17589): Shutting down VM
07-18 00:09:58.945: W/dalvikvm(17589): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f602a0)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589): java.lang.ClassCastException: hasebou.karim.simplify.MessageListDetails cannot be cast to hasebou.karim.simplify.SoundDetails
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at hasebou.karim.simplify.TimedEventsListFragment$TimedEventsAdapter.getView(TimedEventsListFragment.java:260)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2468)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2303)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4655)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4655)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4655)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4655)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4655)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1520)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4655)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4655)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4655)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4655)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2017)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1838)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1131)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4611)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-18 00:09:58.955: E/AndroidRuntime(17589):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

that's complete_event_discription.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/timed_events_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/state"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="isActivated"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and that's message_list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeToSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contactName"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/timeToSend"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeToSend"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timeToSend"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ConvertView only is == to null the first time the view is built. Thereafter, it is no longer null, so the "if(isMessage == false)
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.complete_event_discription, null);" will never be called

Comment: @Shadesblade you should probably turn that into an answer

Comment: Oh, right. I've been commenting a bit too much lately, hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the adapter interface properly. You should never be relying on some boolean in getView() to determine this sort of thing -- that's what the `viewType()` methods on adapter are for. Override `BaseAdapter` and handle the implementation yourself, and this will be much simpler. For explanation:

```
public class TimedEventsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_SOUND = 1;

    private final List<Object> mItems;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public TimedEventsAdapter(Context context, List<Object> objects) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Ensure that mItems is never null, even if a null object list
        // is received.
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
        if (objects != null) {
            mItems.addAll(objects);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // Just return the item in the appropriate position in the list
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // Arbitrary value here since there is no unique identifier for the data
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

        // Initialize the View based on the view type (provided by getItemViewType())
        // Set a tag with an appropriate ViewHolder type to avoid findViewById() calls
        // on every iteration.
        if (convertView == null) {
           if (VIEW_TYPE_SOUND == viewType) {
               convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.complete_event_description, parent, false);
               convertView.setTag(new SoundViewHolder(convertView));
           } else if (VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE == viewType) {
               convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.message_list_view, parent, false);
               convertView.setTag(new MessageViewHolder(convertView));
           }
        }

        // Update the View based on the view type. You know that you will have a non-null
        // View and appropriate ViewHolder set as a tag since that's been confirmed above.
        if (VIEW_TYPE_SOUND == viewType) {
            SoundDetails device = (SoundDetails) getItem(position);
            SoundViewHolder holder = (SoundViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            holder.eventName.setText(device.name);
            holder.eventTime.setText(device.time);
            holder.state.setChecked(device.isEventActive);
            holder.state.setTag(position);
        } else if (VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE == viewType) {
            MessageListDetails details = (MessageListDetails) getItem(position);
            MessageViewHolder holder = (MessageViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            holder.contactName.setText(details.contactName);
            holder.contactNumber.setText(details.contactNumber);
            holder.timeToSend.setText(details.sendingTime);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // Return the number of different view types to be eligible 
        // for View recycling.
        return VIEW_TYPE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Figure out what type of data is at the given position.
        // instanceOf isn't very efficient -- it would be beter 
        // if the objects shared a base class that described what
        // they were, but for this example it will work.
        if (getItem(position) instanceof SoundDetails) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_SOUND;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE;
        }
    }

    //
    // Simple classes for holding references to views
    //

    private static class SoundViewHolder {
        final TextView eventName;
        final TextView eventTime;
        final Switch state;

        SoundViewHolder(View v) {
            eventName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
            eventTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
            state = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.state);
        }
    }

    private static class MessageViewHolder {
        final TextView contactName;
        final TextView contactNumber;
        final TextView timeToSend;

        MessageViewHolder(View v) {
            contactName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            contactNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactNumber);
            timeToSend = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeToSend);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! And not really but there's not much more complicated than this. You're basically responsible for four method implementations: `getCount()` (just provide a number for how many items `getView()` should be called for; `getItem()` which usually just means return the item at that index in your dataset -- the only time it really should be complicated is if you're merging multiple datasets together; `getItemId()` which is usually only used if you're pulling from a SQLite database; and then `getView()` which is where you bind the View to the item at the given position in your data set.

Answer (score 0):

ConvertView only is == to null the first time the view is built. Thereafter, it is no longer null, so the `if(isMessage == false) v = vi.inflate(R.layout.complete_event_discription, null);` will never be called

Comment: even when I removed the if(contextview == null) exception occurs. what am saying is I call prepareForIncomingMessage to change Boolean value to true yet it stays false and goes to the executes the if statement.

Comment: This could be caused by a nested LinearLayout (causing the getView() to be called twice for position 0 the first time around). It's a bug that has always been around. What's your xml look like for the two layouts.

Comment: I have added my layout. the first has a relativeLayout with LinearLayout nested inside of it. is their a way I could keep the same ui but make it in without the nested layouts

Comment: No, that's not the bug I was referring to. A LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout should be fine. Honestly, the fact you are having two different rootviews for your ListView means you should be creating a custom view that extends BaseAdapter. Sadly, since there doesn't seem to be an easy fix, you're going to have to do that. Well, frankly, for what you are doing you should be doing that anyway.

Comment: Otherwise, it's beyond me. Frankly I always create Custom Views that extend BaseAdapter, so I'm not entirely sure what ArrayAdapter is doing, but I assumed it was the same.

Comment: i tried using the baseAdapter but I failed to do it. whenever I move to another activity and go back everything would be erased and updating the ui was annoying. couldn't do it properly. anyways thanks for trying